# Is there an issue with CDHtmlDialog and the HTML video tag?

Tags: html, visual-c++, windows-7, mfc, internet-explorer-11

I've an old MFC project, whre I queue up html sites and set their on-screen time.
This time I wanted to add a video to my queue so I made a site with the the vide tag.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>myVideo</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!--2:07-->
    <video src="../picPool/myVideo.mp4" width="1024" height="768" autoplay>Ihr Browser kann dieses Video nicht wiedergeben.</video>
  </body>
</html>
```

This works perfectly fine in Internet explorer 11, Windows 7 x32 SP1,  if I check the box Options->Advanced->Security->allow active content to run in files on my computer. It works on the exact same computer where I'm trying tu run my program. But I only get "**Ihr Browser kann dieses Video nicht wiedergeben.**".

A qui loockup on stackoverflow or googler reveals nothing specific.

I don't get it,CDHtmlDialog should use the same dll as that IE11, right? I try to get the old project to work, debug and see if there is anything weird.
I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: It looks like it has nothing to do with `CHtmlDialog`. In your computer IE can play .mp4 files, in another computer it cannot. It's a browser question.

Comment: I'd run the html file on the same computer with IE 11 as the application with the CHtmlDialog.

Comment: A collegue of me told me this is a global setting for the CHtmlDialog. the application won't work with earlier versions of IE then anymore.
i'll post a solution when I've the code finished.